# What can be used instead of ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

Tags: php, header, buffer

What can be used instead of `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` which is causing `PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0`?

Some, as I believe, related and/or helpful questions asked before:
["Unknown" PHP error - what is that supposed to mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651548/unknown-php-errors-what-thats-supposed-to-be)
[PHP warning: headers already sent in Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622192/php-warning-headers-already-sent-in-unknown)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me (finally) was to put `zlib.output_compression` in php.ini and set it to ON, successfuly replacing `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`

Answer (score 0):

Just put `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` *at the start* of the chain of PHP statements. If PHP emits that warning it means this call isn't at the start.

Comment: No, in this case this seems to be a bug. See her previous question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want some alternatives, you could set in your php.ini:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Or in .htaccess if your PHP runs as an Apache module:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
```

Here you can use the `<Files>` or `<FilesMatch>` directive to limit compression to the files you want.

Actually you can set this property in your PHP script too, but I don't think that it will work: `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On')`...

---

Debug question: If you set `header('X-something: x');` before `ob_start()`, does the `header()` function cause the same error?